# HTML5 Audio pause not working

Tags: javascript, html, audio

```
document.getElementById('s/' + currentRadio + '/' + currentSong).pause();
```

This is currently not pausing the audio while this works fine playing it

```
document.getElementById('s/' + currentRadio + '/' + currentSong).play();
```

If I manually enter on the js console the pause code the audio will stop... so no idea whats goin on.

If I try this

```
console.log(document.getElementById('s/' + currentRadio + '/' + currentSong));
```

I will get the div so everything seems okey.

```
<audio class="playSong" id="s/0/0" src="/music/Playback FM/Big Daddy Kane - Warm It Up, Kane.mp3"></audio>
```

The audio tag are inside

```
<div class="radioAudio">

    </div>
```

And the pause button is made like this

```
$('#tuneRadioPause').click(function(e) {
    if(currentSong !== -1 && currentPlay) {
        console.log("s/" + currentRadio + "/" + currentSong)
        document.getElementById('s/' + currentRadio + '/' + currentSong).pause();
        currentPlay = false;
    }

    if(!currentPlay && currentSong !== -1) {
        document.getElementById('s/' + currentRadio + '/' + currentSong).play();
        currentPlay = true;
    }
});
```

Comment: Could you also show parent divs if any? as well as relevant html for button, placement of script

Comment: Seems like a `window.onload` issue. Is your javascript wrapped in a `window.onload`? If you are using jQuery you might need to use `$(window).load`. But if the pause is triggered by a user event that won't matter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated**

The problem is the conditional checks. Both `if`'s are run regardless. This means that when the first condition is met (`... && currentPlay`) `currentPlay` is set to `false` and audio is paused.

Then when the second check is run right after independently (`!currentPlay && ...`), `currentPlay` is *already* `false` so this condition is *also* met and then `play()` is triggered right away making it appear as if pause didn't work.

Solve by using an `else` statement like this:

```
$('#tuneRadioPause').click(function(e) {
    if(currentSong !== -1 && currentPlay) {
        console.log("s/" + currentRadio + "/" + currentSong)
        document.getElementById('s/' + currentRadio + '/' + currentSong).pause();
        currentPlay = false;
    }

    else if(!currentPlay && currentSong !== -1) {          // else here!!
        document.getElementById('s/' + currentRadio + '/' + currentSong).play();
        currentPlay = true;
    }
});
```

I would recommend using the actual status of the audio element to check though rather than unbound flags, for example:

```
$('#tuneRadioPause').click(function(e) {
    if (currentSong < 0 || currentRadio < 0) return;

    var audio = document.getElementById('s/' + currentRadio + '/' + currentSong);
    if (null === audio || audio.readyState === audio.HAVE_NOTHING) return;

    if(!audio.paused && !audio.ended) {
        audio.pause();
    }
    else if (audio.paused) {
        audio.play();
    }

    //currentPlay = !audio.paused;  // not needed anymore, but may somewhere else?
});
```

```js
var currentSong = 0, currentRadio = 0;

document.getElementById('s/' + currentRadio + '/' + currentSong).oncanplay = function() {$('#tuneRadioPause')[0].disabled = false}

$('#tuneRadioPause').click(function(e) {
    if (currentSong < 0 || currentRadio < 0) return;

    var audio = document.getElementById('s/' + currentRadio + '/' + currentSong);
    if (null === audio || audio.readyState === audio.HAVE_NOTHING) return;

    if(!audio.paused && !audio.ended) {
        audio.pause();
    }
    else if (audio.paused) {
        audio.play();
    }

    //currentPlay = !audio.paused;  // not needed anymore, but may somewhere else?
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<audio preload="auto" class="playSong" id="s/0/0" src="https://github.com/epistemex/free-music-for-test-and-demo/blob/master/music/kf_colibris.mp3?raw=true"></audio><br>
<button disabled id="tuneRadioPause">Play / Pause</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this:

```
var audio = document.getElementById("yourAudio"); 

function pauseAudio() { 
    audio.pause(); 
}
```